# Cross-Origin Request Blocked error while Requesting WebAPI services

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, cors, netbeans-8

I am working on a OJET framework project on NetBeans. And I am making a call to .Net WebAPI service through Ajax. The request is reaching the server fine and it is getting processed fine, anyhow while receiving the data I can the below error in browser console.

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource"

I know I am working on cross platforms but not sure how to resolve this issue.
Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you enable CORS on your webApi? If yes, maybe the fireware is blocking this kind of request

Comment: It's not clear if you have control on the Web API implementation or not. Anyway [you need to enable Cross-Origin Requests](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) (CORS) on the Web API project.